# PHP preg_replace text variable

Tags: php, string, replace, variables, echo

I want to echo a string with the variable inside including the ($) like so:

```
echo "$string";
```

I dont want it to echo the variable for string, I want it to echo '$string' itself, and not the contents of a variable. I know I can do this by adding a '\' in front of the ($), but I want to use preg_replace to do it. I tried this and it doesnt work:

```
$new = preg_replace("/\$/","\\$",$text);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) for your string declaration:

```
echo '$string';
```

Variables inside single quotes do not get expanded:

> **Note:** Unlike the two other syntaxes, [variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) and escape sequences for special characters will ***not*** be expanded when they occur in single quoted [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Another solution would be to escape the `$` like you already did within the `preg_replace` call:

```
echo "\$string";
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can't use `preg_replace` to do what you want. `preg_replace`gets its arguments after variable substitution takes place.

So either there's nothing for `preg_replace`to replace (because the substitution already occurred), or there is no need for `preg_replace`to do anything (because the dollar sign was already escaped).

Answer (score 0):

As you observed, the `$` is treated for variable interpolation inside double quoted strings. So your regex pattern should be constructed using single quoted strings as well. Also, the `$` is a special character inside the regex-replacement string, so you need to escape it extra:

```
preg_replace('/\$/', '\\\\$', $text)
```

But there is no need for the preg_ function here. str_replace should do it:

```
str_replace('$', '\\$', $text)
```

This might clear things up for you, but as Gumbo suggests: why not use single quotes to echo?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you want to remove the text which exists in some variables. Then you can do it like

```
 $foo = '123';  
 $bar = 'bqwe';                      
 $str= preg_replace("/".$foo ."/", '', $str, 1);
 $str= preg_replace("/".$bar ."/", '', $str, 1);
```